# Flutter: How to limit bouncing scorll physics?

Tags: flutter

(Edited question for clarity)

[image: Text]

I want to limit the height of white space `BouncingScrollPhysics` creates. The white space (offset) is determined by the scrolling velocity. Is there a way to limit the offset?

Answer (score 1):

you can add this parameter to reduce that gap when being scrolled while using bouncing scroll physics.

```
BouncingScrollPhysics(decelerationRate: ScrollDecelerationRate.fast)
```

if you want to customize it more complex you can create custom scroll widget

Answer (score 0):

Go inside the BouncingScrollPhysics documentation by `Ctrl` + `Click`.

Copy paste the BouncingScrollPhysics Class and change the name of it. Inside that you can see a function named

```dart
  double frictionFactor(double overscrollFraction) {
    switch (decelerationRate) {
      case ScrollDecelerationRate.fast:
        return 0.26 * math.pow(1 - overscrollFraction, 2);
      case ScrollDecelerationRate.normal:
        return 0.52 * math.pow(1 - overscrollFraction, 2);
    }
  }
```

change the double value under the ScrollDecelerationRate.normal to whatever rate you want. Between 0 to 0.52.

I have changed it to 0.04 and it do reduces the bounce. Try playing with the values and stop when you get the required behaviour.

```dart
  double frictionFactor(double overscrollFraction) {
    switch (decelerationRate) {
      case ScrollDecelerationRate.fast:
        return 0.26 * math.pow(1 - overscrollFraction, 2);
      case ScrollDecelerationRate.normal:
        return 0.04 * math.pow(1 - overscrollFraction, 2);
    }
  }
```

Note: I am not sure if this is the right answer or not. But I think it will reduce a little bit of the bounce. You can also play with other values too to find the right one.

Answer (score -1):

The ScrollPhysics class can be changed by using a **CustomScrollView** widget 
for example:

```
 CustomScrollView(
  physics: new ClampingScrollPhysics(),
 
);
```

In this example `ClampingScrollPhysics()` will just stop at the end view

 You can look for more `Scrollphysics` properties in the flutter docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html

Comment: There are more features in that class that you can choose from, and if you still want to keep the bouncing you can use **BouncingScrollPhysics** witch you can find all about it in the link in my answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, can you be more specific?